# What does "attack drop" mean for a Charged Attack in Trainer Battles?

Tags: pokemon-go

I assume that for Pokemon Go Battle League the "Trainer Battles" details for a Pokemon are what matters.  So I was looking at the card for a Charizard and under the "Trainer Battles" for its Overheat attack it has an "ATTACK DROP" note (see image below).  What does "ATTACK DROP" mean?  When and why does it appear or apply?

[image]

Other notes I have seen:

- DEFENSE DROP
- OPPONENT DEFENSE DROP
- OPPONENT DEFENSE DROP CHANCE
- ATTACK BOOST

Answer (score 2):

In Trainer Battles, your attack and defense stats are scaled by a BuffMultiplier, whose value starts at 1.  Certain charge moves may have a side effect of boosting or dropping those stats in stages.  The range of values is [1/2, 4/7, 2/3, 4/5, 1, 5/4, 3/2, 7/4, 2].

The notes under certain charge moves have four parts - two required and two optional - to describe the move's side effect.

```
<opponent> [attack|defense] [boost|drop] <chance>
```

If chance appears, the move has a certain probability for that side effect to occur.  The range of possible probabilities is [1/10, 1/8, 1/5, 3/10, 1/2].  Technically, all side effects have a probability, where the lack of chance means a probability of 1.

Answer (score 1):

This will change your (or your opponents) attack or defense stat in a trainer battle. In a raid battle, there are no (or not yet) such stat changes. The impact is roughly 25% extra attack/defense per stage (there are attacks that can increase it with two stages, such as Ancient Power) in case you increase it. The decrease (on yourself or opponent) is around 20%. Take a look around [here](https://www.pvpchart.com/stat-boost-pokemon.html) for all moves and percentages.

Comment: So for trainer battles a particular "stat boost" *always* applies to the specified Pokemons and moves as described in that "Stat Boost" link?  E.g., Charizard will *always* have Attack Drop with Overheat?

Comment: Also the descriptions on the [Stat Boost chart](https://www.pvpchart.com/stat-boost-pokemon.html) are confusing.  What does it mean for a charged move to "increase your defense?"  And what is the difference between *increasing your attack* and *decreasing opponent's defense* – aren't those equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

As [Mathias711 said](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/379215/176959), these different effects cause a drop in that stat.*

- If it says **ATTACK/DEFENSE** ***BOOST***, then it will increase that stat for your Pokémon.
- However, if it says **DEFENSE/ATTACK DROP/BOOST** ***CHANCE***, then it has a chance to drop/boost that stat.*

* Stat boosts/drops are not permanent and only applies to that match.

** targets opponent's Pokémon if it says ***OPPONENT*** **ATTACK/DEFENSE DROP/BOOST (CHANCE)**. Otherwise, it will affect *your* Pokémon.

Comment: Not even the whole match necessarily, it also gets cleared if you switch.